# SQL Server 2012 Installation Has No Option To Uninstall

Tags: sql-server-2012, windows

I've recently inherited a laptop for testing from a client, unfortunately it wasn't a fresh image so it has some software already installed that's causing me some grief.

The short version is their IT department has had some issues, I think the only person still working there is the guy that makes the tea, and they've asked me to setup an easy to deploy SQL Server 2012 installation and instance (easy enough, this is scripted and ready to go) the issue is that SQL Server 2012 is already installed on the laptop and there's no option to uninstall it through Add/Remove, so I can't do a test install for them to look at.

I'm thinking that the installation is corrupt, and I'm going to have to either A) Remove it all manually and hope I get all the registry keys and associated files, or B) Send it back to the client and wait for them to send me another laptop (This one's not preferable, like I said they're having a number of issues with their IT department and I'm pretty sure I'm just going to get the same laptop back as it is now)

Am I right in thinking this is a botched/corrupted installation, or have I missed something? It's windows 7 professional, logging in with a local admin account. I've been able to uninstall some other applications.

I checked some other posts on here and it sounds similar to ;
[How to uninstall SQL server 2012 not showing in control panel's "Programs and features"](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/68373/how-to-uninstall-sql-server-2012-not-showing-in-control-panels-programs-and-fe)

Thanks for your opinion.
Neil

Comment: You haven't given any info that differs from your linked Q and A, why not try what Shanky recommended?

Comment: That's the plan at the moment, I was just putting this on here in case I was missing something

Comment: [And this approach didn't work](https://sqlblog.org/2010/10/25/fun-with-software-uninstalling-sql-server-2008-r2-evaluation-edition)? Did you **try** it?

Comment: Uninstalling through Add/Remove in the control panel? Yes (Well kind of, the option just isn't there, right clicking doesn't bring up a menu of any sort)

I'm holding off on anything registry related just in case someone comes up with an obvious step that I've missed.

Comment: Ok try suggestion mentioned and revert if you face with any issue. As you said installation is totally broken removing few reg keys might help but if you still face issue I would say, IF POSSIBLE, format the laptop and start fresh installation of OS and SQL Server although this is not a good solution but does helps

Comment: I tried removing it using Shanky's suggestion and things seem ok. Thanks for the suggestions everyone